# Bounty spelling wrong in tabs?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, new-nav, spelling

"Bounty" seems to be misspelled in the default title for browser title and in the SO tabs.

[image]

You can reproduce this by filtering a tag by questions with "bounties" and then ordering by bounty size.

Comment: [This link here should reproduce the bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size)

Comment: @Quill-HATMANIAC that link appears to be broken - at least for me (I'm assuming there's no rep requirement there that I don't have...)

Comment: Well it works for me and four others, and I have less reputation that you...

Comment: Same issue as @Jeff

Comment: i am also getting page not found.

Comment: @Jeff It is **[new-nav]**. Have you registered for that?

Comment: I think the question should be *Boutny spelling wrong in tabs?*

Comment: Mutiny on the Boutny.

Comment: I think you mean mutniy?

Comment: For the record, I have [new-nav] and the link works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in build `2015.12.16.3985` (meta) and  `2015.12.16.3090` (main).